# Compute Riemann Sum

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

I was not formally taught how to evaluate Riemann sums using the summation rule, and so I am going off of solutions to other problems to apply to my own problem.  However, I am stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

~Edited per comments below

**Question**
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Big( 2 + \frac{6i}{n} \Big)^{-2} = $$
Let $x = \frac{i}{n}$. So, now we need to find our upper and lower bounds, which are given by:
$$\frac{b-a}{n} = \frac{1}{n}$$

Therefore,  $a =0, b=1$. Now, we can convert our Riemann Sum into an integral:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Big( 2 + \frac{6i}{n} \Big)^{-2} = \int_{0}^{1} (2 + 6x)^{-2}dx$$

Let $u = 2 + 6x$, so $du = 6 dx$. Our bounds now change from $u = 2 + 6(0) = 2$ and $u = 2 + 6(1) = 8$.

Now,
$$\int_{2}^{8} \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{u^{2}} du = \frac{1}{6} \int_{2}^{8} \frac{1}{u^{2}} du  = - \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{u} |_{2}^{8} $$
$$ = \frac{1}{6} \Big[ \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{8} \Big]$$
$$ = \frac{1}{16}.$$

Comment: Is this a Riemann Sum?

Comment: Yes, this is a Riemann Sum problem

Comment: What are you doing? Set up the integral.

Comment: How would I set up the integral? I take it the bounds are from [0,1] but what would be the integrand?

Comment: $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{36x^{2} + 2x +4}dx$?

Comment: $\int_0^1\frac1{(2+6x)^2}dx$

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $\frac{1}{16}$.

Comment: Thanks @BobDobbs.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^\infty f\left(\frac kn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$